# How to bind N selects based on N elements in array (*ngFor)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ngmodel

I'm struggling on this problem quite a bit. In my example I have **N** cards as many selects. 
 I assigned every select a name using an id from the `cardsArray` so every name is unique, but when a value is choosen all the others fill up with the same value even if they are untouched. 
 
**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="card shadow col-4 p-1" *ngFor="let card of cardsArray">
   <div class="card-header">
    <strong class="card-title text-danger">Select your favorite fruit</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
    <select
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedFruit"
      [name]="'select-' + card.id"
    >
      <option *ngFor="let fruit of selectArray" [ngValue]="fruit.emoji">
        {{ fruit.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">You selected: {{ selectedFruit }}</div>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'multiple-select';

 cardsArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'First' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Second' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Third' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Fourth' }
 ]

 selectedFruit: string = '';

 selectArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Banana', emoji: '' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Apple', emoji: '' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Pineapple', emoji: '' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Kiwi', emoji: '' }
 ]
}
```

How could I resolve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You binded them all with the same `selectedFruit` variable. You should bind them with different variables so they can have different values in the same time.

You can change change the `selectedFruit` to be an object, and bind the select with the properties of that object:

```js
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'multiple-select';

 cardsArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'First' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Second' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Third' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Fourth' }
 ]

 selectedFruit: any = {};

 selectArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Banana', emoji: '' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Apple', emoji: '' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Pineapple', emoji: '' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Kiwi', emoji: '' }
 ]
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="card shadow col-4 p-1" *ngFor="let card of cardsArray">
   <div class="card-header">
    <strong class="card-title text-danger">Select your favorite fruit</strong>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
    <select
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedFruit[card.name]"
      [name]="'select-' + card.id"
    >
      <option *ngFor="let fruit of selectArray" [ngValue]="fruit.emoji">
        {{ fruit.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">You selected: {{ selectedFruit[card.name] }}</div>
</div>
```

Now `selectedFruit` will store the value of all 4 selects in relevant properties `First`, `Second`, `Third` and `Fourth`.

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gxrgmb?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do not know how many selectedFruit variables I need.

Comment: For each select one.

Comment: How do I instanciate them? Could you post some code?